# How to avoid an infinite loop (hide rows) with onSelectionChange(e) please?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, row, hide

I made this script to hide the row of the cell I clicked. But obviously, once the row is hidden, my selection stays on a new cell and my script continues to hide the new row, without stopping. Makes sense but is there a way to only hide one row? I guess not since onSelectionChange(e) does its job here.

Thanks for your advice.

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {  
var range = e.range;  
var aa = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var bb = aa.getActiveSheet();
var activerow = range.getRow();
bb.hideRows(activerow)
}
```

Comment: Create a column with tickboxes and change to `onEdit(e)`?  otherwise you could use the property service to store a boolean and use that inside a if statement.

Comment: @RemcoE33 Hello. Good idea, it works very fine. My problem now is too change back the checkbox value to FALSE just after the row is hidden (so I can click again to hide it). Still a beginner.

function onEdit(e){
if (e.value != "TRUE") return;
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().hideRows(e.range.rowStart);
}

Comment: After hiding add `e.range.setValue(FALSE)`

Comment: Perfect thanks @Martín. I was testing "var cell = sheet.getCurrentCell();var newCell = cell.offset(-1, 0)" to target the cell above but your proposal is fine too lol. Thank to you both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, here is my answer, maybe it will help someone :

**Here is the code to hide a row using a checkbox + the checkbox turns to false just after so you can click it again later** :

```
function onEdit(e) {
    if (e.value != "TRUE") return;
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().hideRows(e.range.rowStart);
    e.range.setValue(false)
}
```

**Here is the code to unhide all hidden rows/columns** :

```
function unhideallrowscolumns() {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('cc')
    const allrows = sheet.getRange("A:A");
    const allcolumns = sheet.getRange("1:1");
    sheet.unhideRow(allrows);
    sheet.unhideColumn(allcolumns);
}
```

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

To hide a single row instead of of `SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.hideRows` use `SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.hideRow`, example:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {  
  e.range.getSheet().hideRow(e.range.rowStart);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your proposal. Unfortunately this script doesn't work for me. And if I change "hideRow" by "hideRows" it goes again for infinite hidden rows as my first script. Maybe I am doing something wrong. I have posted a solution, but there is probably something smarter.